# Error Creating PhoneGap 3.0.0 Custom iOS Plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm having an issue following PhoneGap's [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_ios_plugin.md.html#iOS%20Plugins) for creating a custom iOS plugin.  I keep getting the error

> Plugin 'Echo' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml

I keep checking config.xml and it's exactly what the documentation has.  Am I missing something?

config.xml

```
<plugins>
    <plugin name="Echo" value="Echo" />
</plugins>
```

index.html

```
function hello()
{
  var success = function(){ alert('success'); };
  var error = function(error){ alert('error ' + error); };

  cordova.exec(success, error, "Echo", "echo", ["hey"]);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I had two problems.

1. I was using the wrong `config.xml`.  I was playing with the one under the `www` directory and not the one in the root directory.
2. The documentation was using both `<plugin />` and `<feature/>` and it turns out that `<feature/>` is the right thing to use.

   ```
   <feature name="Echo">
       <param name="ios-package" value="Echo" />
   </feature>
   ```

Somewhere it also says that `<plugins />` is deprecated so I didn't put it under that node either and it still works.

Comment: Your comment about using the wrong config.xml file was the answer for me! I was also tripped up by the conflicting references to <plugins /> and <feature> in the official documentation.

Comment: I'm updating my plugins it runs on cordova2.2.0. Do the plugins files(javascript one) must be in the plugins folder found in the root directory? Also do I have to put an entry under cordova_plugins.json?

Comment: What do you mean "not the one in the root." In a fresh install, there isn't a `config.xml` in the root. I tried editing the one in `www`, but it didn't work. If I edit the one in `platform/ios/AppName/config.xml` and build in Xcode, it works, but the next `phonegap` build will clobber that `config.xml` (as expected).